# Can't produce to Confluent Kafka topic through Kafka REST API

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, kafka-rest, confluent-cloud

**I have a trouble producing to Kafka topic through Rest API proxy.**

I have a running confluent kafka cluster in which I'd like to create a topic and produce a message to it using REST API.

For that purpose I have followed the documentation and created API key and secret.

**I manage to create topic:**

```
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Basic <BASE64_ENCODED_AUTH_KEY_SECRET>"  \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d "{\"topic_name\":\"test1\",\"partitions_count\":6,\"configs\":[]}" \
https://pkc-xmzwx.europe-central2.gcp.confluent.cloud:443/kafka/v3/clusters/lkc-1zoqz/topics" | jq 

-------------------
returns:
{
  "kind": "KafkaTopic",
  "metadata": {
    "self": "https://pkc-xmzwx.europe-central2.gcp.confluent.cloud/kafka/v3/clusters/lkc-1zoqz/topics/test1",
    "resource_name": "crn:///kafka=lkc-1zoqz/topic=test1"
  },
  "cluster_id": "lkc-1zoqz",
  "topic_name": "test1",
  "is_internal": false,
  "replication_factor": 0,
  "partitions_count": 0,
  "partitions": {
    "related": "https://pkc-xmzwx.europe-central2.gcp.confluent.cloud/kafka/v3/clusters/lkc-1zoqz/topics/test1/partitions"
  },
  "configs": {
    "related": "https://pkc-xmzwx.europe-central2.gcp.confluent.cloud/kafka/v3/clusters/lkc-1zoqz/topics/test1/configs"
  },
  "partition_reassignments": {
    "related": "https://pkc-xmzwx.europe-central2.gcp.confluent.cloud/kafka/v3/clusters/lkc-1zoqz/topics/test1/partitions/-/reassignment"
  },
  "authorized_operations": []
}
```

**MY PROBLEM:**
**I can't produce to that topic (can't produce to ANY topic through Kafka Rest API) :**

```
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Basic <BASE64_ENCODED_AUTH_KEY_SECRET>"  \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
--data "{"records":[{"value":"S2Fma2E="}]}" \
"https://pkc-xmzwx.europe-central2.gcp.confluent.cloud:443/kafka/v3/clusters/lkc-1zoqz/topics/test1"  
    

-----------------
returns:
    {"error_code":405,"message":"HTTP 405 Method Not Allowed"}
```

**ALSO TRIED LIKE THIS:**

```
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Basic <BASE64_ENCODED_AUTH_KEY_SECRET>"  \
                   -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
                    -d  "{ \"key\": {\"value\": \"S2Fma2E=\"} }" \
                   "https://pkc-xmzwx.europe-central2.gcp.confluent.cloud:443/kafka/v3/clusters/lkc-1zoqz/topics/test1/records"  

----------------
Returns the same:

    {"error_code":405,"message":"HTTP 405 Method Not Allowed"}
```

IDK if this has something to do with ACL management? Looking into that right now....

Comment: `405 Method Not Allowed` means the server doesn't define a method for the route provided. In other words, your original error is saying a route for `POST /v3/clusters/{cluster_id/topics/{topic_id}` doesn't exist, which according to the linked docs page, it doesn't... If you get a **401/403** error, then that's Unauthorized/Forbidden and might be ACL related. Other than that, opening a Confluent Cloud support ticket would be a better option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using Confluent Platform (hosted) or Confluent Cloud API?

If the latter, this API is not supported, here's the documentation on what's supported by Cloud API: https://docs.confluent.io/cloud/current/api.html

Comment: Yep, just realized that.. However I should say that it better be written that the complete REST API is not implemented and those and those features are missing... But it is also my bad as well.. Cheers.

Comment: Totally agree with you.

Comment: If you ever run into this again, just open up the browser dev tools and see what it's doing.